# Is there any section of 4chan that is suitable for worldbuilding questions?

Tags: discussion, community

While Reddit has [the obvious place for this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/), I have no idea, where to start similar discussions on 4chan.

Should I do it at all? Or is it a rather bad idea?

/tg/ seems to be suitable only for D&D campaign settings.

Comment: I think the first question to be asked is, "How many people here use 4chan enough to know the threads of the site?" I know I've never even been to the site.

Comment: I generally view 4chan as the roiling puss bucket of the internet, I wouldn't tend to go there for help or valid information.

Comment: What's the connection between Worldbuilding.SE and 4chan?  (Just trying to understand why this question belongs on our meta.)

Comment: I think Zoltan is thinking a meta site on SE is akin to a talk page on a wikipedia article.  He's not far off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the comments identifying 4chan as an unsavory place are well-founded, I don't think it's true that unsavory places have nothing to offer the intrepid world-builder.

/tg/ certainly has a gaming world bias, but it's also populated by sundry sci-fi and medieval fantasy nerds who often provide feedback that is broadly applicable to the task of worldbuilding.

There is also a literature board, where any literature except fanfiction can be discussed.  Presumably "fanfiction" does not cover workshopping original worlds.  This is the closest I can find to the old text only board they used to have for writers, back when I was an active user.

The various topical boards may also be of use to you for particular questions, especially if your primary interest is in fringe theories.  The Paranormal, Science & Math, and History & Humanities boards are likely suspects for fruitful discussions, particularly if you find your questions getting "serioused out" of SE sites.

Answer (score -1):

Never use 4chan, ever, unless you want unsettling pornography and people committing suicide on live streams I would recommend stay away. Also there isn't a real way to track your post, as far as I am aware.

Comment: There's a lot more to 4chan than /b/