# Do we need the [4chan] tag on Meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

I want to discuss the usage of the [4chan](/questions/tagged/4chan) tag on Meta, as I think it is unnecessary.

While looking through our Meta tags I found the [4chan](/questions/tagged/4chan) tag which belongs to this question:

[Is there any section of 4chan that is suitable for worldbuilding questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/is-there-any-section-of-4chan-that-is-suitable-for-worldbuilding-questions)

The question itself looks like it would be better on a Meta Site from 4chan (if something like that exists; I don't know much about the site). There hasn't been any activity on the question in roughly a year, it's currently at +0/-3 with one answer of +2/-0 and one answer of +0/-2. The positive answer suggests some topics on 4chan that might be useful for WorldBuilders who are having trouble with their questions getting closed here on WorldBuilding.SE.

The [4chan](/questions/tagged/4chan) tag doesn't have any tag description or tag wiki. As far as I can tell it hasn't been used for any other question. It's sole purpose in the last year seems to have been this one moderately downvoted question about places on 4chan to ask worldbuilding questions.

This tag doesn't seem to be useful for our community, so in my opinion it would be best to remove it. What does the community think? Do we need the [4chan](/questions/tagged/4chan) tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've removed the tag.  I've also closed the question, which is asking about *4chan*, not about *Worldbuilding* (our site).  Meta is for questions about our site or about the SE software, not about where else on the Internet to ask worldbuilding questions.  (It would be possible to ask a worldbuilding-resources question *on main* that involves other sites, but that's not what happened here.)